# Android piechart with icons between bars

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I want to create a pie chart with images in between the legend bars. I am adding the screenshot below for better understanding, i tried using one canvas and then created one arc and tried to add images to it, but it was not working. For now i am using below pie chart library to show the bars with center text. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks :)

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTCdv.png)

Regards,
Rohit Garg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by extending [PieChartRenderer](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/PieChartRenderer.html).

If you look at the implementation of `PieChartRenderer.drawRoundedSlices(Canvas c)` you can get an example of how to get the starting coordinates of each slice.

Then just use [drawBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint) or [drawPicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPicture(android.graphics.Picture,%20android.graphics.Rect)) to render your image between the pie slices. (I used `Utils.drawImage` in the example to mimic the source of `PieChartRenderer`)

As an example, i copied `drawRoundedSlices` and renamed it `drawImageBeforeSlice`. Instead of drawing the arcs, i draw bitmaps.
To make the renderer use the new method, i override `drawExtras` and stick a call to the new method on the end.

```java
class PieChartRendererWithImages extends PieChartRenderer
{
  protected Drawable mImage;

  public PieChartRendererWithImages(PieChart chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, Drawable image) {
    super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    mImage = image;
  }

  /**
   * This draws an image before all pie-slices
   *
   * @param c
   */
  protected void drawImageBeforeSlice(Canvas c) {

    IPieDataSet dataSet = mChart.getData().getDataSet();

    if (!dataSet.isVisible())
      return;

    float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
    float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

    MPPointF center = mChart.getCenterCircleBox();
    float r = mChart.getRadius();

    // calculate the radius of the "slice-circle"
    float circleRadius = (r - (r * mChart.getHoleRadius() / 100f)) / 2f;

    float[] drawAngles = mChart.getDrawAngles();
    float angle = mChart.getRotationAngle();

    for (int j = 0; j < dataSet.getEntryCount(); j++) {

      float sliceAngle = drawAngles[j];

      Entry e = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j);

      // draw only if the value is greater than zero
      if ((Math.abs(e.getY()) > Utils.FLOAT_EPSILON)) {

        float x = (float) ((r - circleRadius)
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((angle + sliceAngle)
                * phaseY)) + center.x);
        float y = (float) ((r - circleRadius)
                * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((angle + sliceAngle)
                * phaseY)) + center.y);

        // draw image instead of arcs            
        Utils.drawImage(
                c,
                mImage,
                (int)x,
                (int)y,
                mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
      }

      angle += sliceAngle * phaseX;
    }
    MPPointF.recycleInstance(center);
  }

  @Override
  public void drawExtras(Canvas c) {
    super.drawExtras(c);
    // use drawImageBeforeSlice in last step of rendering process
    drawImageBeforeSlice(c);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to [set your new renderer](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.html#setRenderer-com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.DataRenderer-) on your PieChart:

```java
myPieChart.setRenderer(new PieChartRendererWithImages(myPieChart, myPieChart.getAnimator(), myPieChart.getViewPortHandler(), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image)));
```

Verified to work by putting it in the MPAndroidChart example:
[image: MPAndroidChart example with custom icons between the slices]

Comment: My previous answer had a couple of mistakes, please see my update.

Comment: thank you very much it is working but in meantime, requirement has changed from moving it center but outside the every arc.

Comment: MPAndroidChart has support for that out of the box. The PieChartActivity in the example demonstrates this (press the 3 dots, and toggle icons). This is done by [setting an icon offset on the `dataSet`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java#L135) and [`setDrawIcon(true)` on each `dataSet` item](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java#L199)